# How do I like a Facebook AppID through IPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, fbconnect

I am developing a iPhone application in which I want to simply 'Like' my own Facebook AppID.

For Facebook integration I am using FBConnect and Graph API (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/README.mdown).

After researching, I found that I was supposed to use the following method, which I attempted to implement in the "DemoAppViewController.m" of the sample code when the 'publishStream' button was selected:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];  //Use an empty dictionary

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"https://graph.facebook.com/163221793740496/likes" 
andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)self];
```

However, my FBRequest.m 'responseString' indicates: {"error":{"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported post request."}}

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

From what I understand, all I need to do is attach my accessToken to https://graph.facebook.com/163221793740496/likes.  What exactly does that mean, and how is it accomplished?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. - In case there was any confusion, my post was in reference to having a user sign into Facebook with their account login via a fb like button in the application. After the user allowed the appropriate permissions, my app would 'like' the AppID with the user's account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't programmatically like a page on Facebook. It would be enthusiastically abused.

Comment: I for one would love to enthusiastically abuse it.

Comment: Where is this stated?

According to Facebook's Developer site:
"You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments and https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes, respectively."

What would you recommend I program to have owners of the application show their support and promote my iPhone app on Facebook?

Comment: Also, in case there was any confusion.  My post was in reference to having a user sign into Facebook with their account login via a fb like button in the app.  After the user allowed the appropriate permissions, my app would 'like' the AppID with the user's account.

Comment: @JRoss The key phrase is "any object that... **has a connection**". Pages and applications do not have a like connection. I would recommend you present them with a UIWebView that has a normal FB Like button that they're allowed to press if they so choose. There are no "appropriate permissions" for your app to like a page/application.